# Not sure which Database rails is using

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a rails app, where I have created users with scaffolding and saved some entries through the browser. It seems to be doing everything correctly.

The problem is I am not sure which database the app is using. I have mysql but no changes are happening there. Is rails using sqlite instead? If so, how can I switch to mysql or another database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure mysql database in `config/database.yml`. Refer http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Here is a sample from my local settings for reference

```
development: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: invoice_development      
  encoding: utf8
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  user_name: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

test:
  <<: *default
  database: invoice_test
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done this and it seems that it is connecting with mysql. But I keep getting :
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Ava
ilable: ["ddevelopment", "test"]

Comment: Do i need to create a new database from mysql itself? Isn't there a way rails can do that?

Comment: RAILS_ENV='development' rake db:create

Comment: seems you have typo: ["ddevelopment", "test"], if that was copied from log output, obviously you missspelled 'development'

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application locally, it is most likely using the `development` database configured in `config/database.yml`.

To double check, you can check the value of `Rails.env` when running your application. E.g. (from the console):

```
2.2.0 :001 > Rails.env
 => "development"
```

Comment: Works now, great. I had misspelled development with 2 d's.. 

Thanks!